# Upgrade to version 5.37 - Database error

Tags: database

I have avoided upgrading for quite a while, but went ahead finally. Here is the error received below, and am completely unsure where to go to edit the field length. Or is the solution to rollback and re-install my backup and resolve it from there.

[Error: Expand internal civicrm group title field to be 255 in length]

Error Field Error Value

Type    DB_Error

Code    -1

Message DB Error: unknown error

Mode    16

UserInfo    ALTER TABLE civicrm_group CHANGE `title` `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name of Group.' [nativecode=1071 ** Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes]

DebugInfo   ALTER TABLE civicrm_group CHANGE `title` `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name of Group.' [nativecode=1071 ** Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes]

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking that this error relates to this server still running MySQL version 5.6. It did come up as a warning during the upgrade, but not indicated as critical to go ahead. I'll see about upgrading to MySQL version 5.7 next and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command before running the upgrade

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_group ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Include the below config in mysql config file

```
innodb_large_prefix=true 
innodb_file_format=barracuda 
innodb_file_per_table=true
```